# React how to store props inside state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state, store

** I want to store props inside the state, but I write that "* TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of null *" here are screenshots ** I get the props from the container component https://ibb.co/dJkfrWh I provide my container component and reducer. When I use props outside the state, everything works fine for me, I only need to save all these props inside the state

```
import React from 'react';
import { MonthBox } from './Month/Month';

export class Profile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accountSettings: [
                {
                    titleSettings: "Username",
                    fullName: this.props.profile.fullName,
                    icon: faUser,
                },

                {
                    titleSettings: "Looking for a job",
                    fullName: this.props.profile.lookingForAJob,
                    icon: faUser,
                },

                {
                    titleSettings: "Looking for a job description",
                    fullName: this.props.profile.lookingForAJobDescription,
                    icon: faUser,
                },

                {
                    titleSettings: "User ID",
                    fullName: this.props.profile.userId,
                    icon: faUser,
                },
            ]
        };
    }
    render() {


        if (!this.props.profile) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>
        }

        const d = new Date();
        const n = d.getMonth();

        return (
            <div>
                // Removed to JSX shorten the code
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**ProfileContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Profile} from './Profile';
import {profileAC} from "../Redux/profile-reduer";
import * as axios from "axios";
import withRouter from "react-router-dom/es/withRouter";

class ProfileReducer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let userId = this.props.match.params.userId;
        axios.get('https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/profile/' + userId).then(response => {
            this.props.profileAC(response.data);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <>
            <Profile {...this.props} />
        </>
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    profile: state.profile.profile,
})

let urlDataRouter = withRouter(ProfileReducer)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {profileAC})(urlDataRouter);
```

**profile-reducer.js**

```
const ADD_PROFILE = "ADD_PROFILE";

let initialState = {
    profile: null,
}

export const profileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state, profile: action.profile
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const profileAC = (profile) => ({
    type: ADD_PROFILE, profile
})
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to understand why this.props.profile has an undefined value for fullName.

Show us the container component and the relevant redux code

Comment: I don't know your use case, but it is generally considered an anti-pattern in react to store passed props into local component state (exceptions generally deal with transitions *over time*). You should instead try to always consume the passed props directly in the render. This will remove any synchronicity issues between the received props and local state.

Comment: See the update on my answer

Answer (score 0):

<s>You have scope issue.  You don't want `this.props` here, you want just `props`. For example: `fullName: props.profile.fullName`.</s>

You're not dispatching your action so that your handler gets called.  Try updating your action method to this:

```
export const profileAC = (profile) => {
    return dispatch => dispatch({ type: ADD_PROFILE, profile });
}
```

Comment: fullName of null